# Make a responsive menu sticky

Tags: html, css, sticky

I'm trying to create a sticky menu that's responsive. I can get the sticky menu to work, and I can get the responsive menu to work (creates a burger menu on mobile), but I can't get the responsive mobile menu to be sticky!

You can see where I've got to here: https://www.cieh.org/responsive-sticky-menu-test/.

Can anyone help please? Code I have as follows:

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}



window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var myTopnav = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
var sticky = myTopnav.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    myTopnav.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    myTopnav.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  z-index: 1;
}

.topnav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #a5a7a8;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #880d53;
  color: white;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myTopnav" class="topnav" style="text-align: center;"><a href="#home">Home</a> <a href="#news">News</a> <a href="#contact">Contact</a> <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a class="icon" onclick="myFunction1()"> <span class="fa fa-bars"></span> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: there's a `sticky` value for `position`, which you can use in such cases

Answer (score 0):

There is a sticky value you can add when using the `position: sticky` properties. Here is a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp) that will help you achieve what you're trying to do if youre wanting to use sticky. If you just want your header to stay at the top you can use a `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`. Normally if you're wanting something to stay at the top at a certain area when you scroll down to, you'll use `sticky`.

I would just add position fixed onto that menu and while its open itll always be fixed in that spot.

```
@media(max-width: 600px) {
    #myTopnav { position: fixed; width: 100%;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't seem to work though. Also if it did, apparently this class doesn't work in Internet Explorer or Edge 15 and earlier versions.

Comment: Yeah this solution wont work on IE but it will for any modern browsers. I've updated the div you want to select and it'll work. you need need to adjust your css because it may be getting overwritten in the media query. adding this inline worked.

Answer (score 0):

> but I can't get the responsive mobile menu to be sticky!

**In the normal state, an element with the id "#myTopnav" has a class "sticky"**

[image]

---

**When the menu opens, by pressing the burger button, the "stick" class disappears**
[image]

**Even if you manually add this class, another rule with more specificity overrides `position` property.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I've tested again and the burger menu is sticky BUT if you scroll down the page and click on it, it doesn't open. It will only open when you're at the top of the page. So I'm guessing it's to do with the javascript that calls the burger menu?